# Angular dynamic number of paths

Tags: angular, dynamic, path, routes

Hello i need to is to create dynamic paths for component...
Smth like this..

localhost:4200/category/category1/category2/category3/category4

Is this only way solving this problem?

```
  {
    path: 'category/:category1',
    component: CategoryComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:category1/:category2',
    component: CategoryComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:category1/:category2/:category3',
    component: CategoryComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:category1/:category2/:category3/:category4',
    component: CategoryComponent,
  },
```

Or do i have any other option?

Answer (score -1):

you must use:

/category/:type

and with the api's retrive the :type to the backend using filters don't do /../...

using a single slash and the filter that your api provide

Answer (score -1):

You can query parameters

```
localhost:4200/category?cat_one=1&cat_two=2&cat_three=3&cat_four=4
```

import activate route

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

On your component's constructor

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params.cat_one);
        console.log(params.cat_two);
        console.log(params.cat_three);
        console.log(params.cat_four);
    });
}
```